# Writing a loop to extract Comtrade data and export them into multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe, undefined

I am writing a loop to extract UN Comtrade export data for each country (say country i) and will export them into individual CSV files by country for later use. So I used the "get.Comtrade" function (written by Stefan a.) as a starting point and looped it through each unique 3-digit country code in the Comtrade data. Plus, I am only interested in obtaining "commodity" "export" data (from country i to any other countries) and will have no use for all other information contained in the "list" extracted using get.Comtrade function, so I will only extract "year", "reporter", "partner", and "trade value" data for each country and assemble them into a CSV table.

To illustrate with an example, I begin with USA (country code=842) in year 2006, so I wrote

`d <- get.Comtrade(r="842", p="all", ps="2006", type="C", rg="2", freq="A")`

which gives me a "list" --> d that contains 2 items "validation" and "data" in which the latter (data) contains 35 variables and is the data frame of interest. However, I only need the following information (as index by their column number):
[2]Year, [10]rtTitle=Reporter, [13]ptTitle=Partner, [32]Trade.Value..US..
so I entered

`df <-  cbind(d$data[2], d$data[10], d$data[13], d$data[32])`

to make a smaller data frame and adjust "trade value" by million USD.

`df$million <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,4]))/1000000`

finally, I export it into a CSV file to the designated working directory

`write.table(df, "~/working directory/data.csv", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep=",")`

This is straightforward and indeed gives me a four-column CSV table. Building on this simple format, I went on to write a loop to obtain a CSV output for each country:

```
    for (i in 1:length(country_list)){  
  d <- get.Comtrade(r="i", p="all", ps="2006", type="C", rg="2", freq="A")
  df <-  cbind(d$data[2], d$data[10], d$data[13], d$data[32])
  df$million <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,4]))/1000000
  myfile <- file.path("~/working directory", paste0("_", i, ".csv"))
  write.table(df, file=myfile, na = "NA", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE, append=FALSE, sep="")
  }
```

But it returns an error message saying that

`Error in [.data.frame(d$data, 2) : undefined columns selected`

indicating an error occurs on the second line of the loop, that is, the columns in `d$data` are `undefined`. So I checked with previous questions on this board pertaining to column name question in list and/or data frame format, trying different methods for literally three days but still not being able to figure out a solution for this problem.

I understand this is supposed to be a very simple loop but I just get bogged down.

What's you guys' take on this? It will be really appreciated if anyone could point out the errors in the **"undefined column"** issue since this pops up all the time in a number of earlier threads I've checked so far.

Thank you.

---

But the way,

In order to execute the code above, one will need Stefan A.'s get.Comtrade code:

```
get.Comtrade <- function(url="http://comtrade.un.org/api/get?"
                         ,maxrec=50000
                         ,type="C"
                         ,freq="A"
                         ,px="HS"
                         ,ps="now"
                         ,r
                         ,p
                         ,rg="all"
                         ,cc="TOTAL"
                         ,fmt="json"
)
{
  string<- paste(url
                 ,"max=",maxrec,"&" #maximum no. of records returned
                 ,"type=",type,"&" #type of trade (c=commodities)
                 ,"freq=",freq,"&" #frequency
                 ,"px=",px,"&" #classification
                 ,"ps=",ps,"&" #time period
                 ,"r=",r,"&" #reporting area
                 ,"p=",p,"&" #partner country
                 ,"rg=",rg,"&" #trade flow
                 ,"cc=",cc,"&" #classification code
                 ,"fmt=",fmt        #Format
                 ,sep = ""
  )

  if(fmt == "csv") {
    raw.data<- read.csv(string,header=TRUE)
    return(list(validation=NULL, data=raw.data))
  } else {
    if(fmt == "json" ) {
      raw.data<- fromJSON(file=string)
      data<- raw.data$dataset
      validation<- unlist(raw.data$validation, recursive=TRUE)
      ndata<- NULL
      if(length(data)> 0) {
        var.names<- names(data[[1]])
        data<- as.data.frame(t( sapply(data,rbind)))
        ndata<- NULL
        for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
          data[sapply(data[,i],is.null),i]<- NA
          ndata<- cbind(ndata, unlist(data[,i]))
        }
        ndata<- as.data.frame(ndata)
        colnames(ndata)<- var.names
      }
      return(list(validation=validation,data =ndata))
    }
  }
}
```

and get a list of reporters from

```
library(rjson)
string <- "http://comtrade.un.org/data/cache/partnerAreas.json"
reporters <- fromJSON(file=string)
reporters <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(reporters$results,rbind)))
```

Comment: One comment: `df <-  cbind(d$data[2], d$data[10], d$data[13], d$data[32])` would be better written as `df <-  d$data[c(2, 10, 13, 32)]`. It would be even better if you used the names of the variables rather than their position.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually tried putting comma after each variable's position in the data frame: df <-  cbind(d$data[2,], d$data[10,], d$data[13,], d$data[32,]). This can make the loop run but generate NA (for all entries) in all CSV outputs and the outputs are missing headers. In addition, it returns a warning message saying that I'm " Coercing LHS to a list" in the following line:
as.numeric(as.character(df[, 4]))/1000000

Comment: I'm not sure how this is responsive to my comment. If `d$data` is a data.frame, then `df <- d$data[c(2, 10, 13, 32)]` subsets the data.frame keeping variables 2, 10, 13, and 32. syntax like `d$data[32,]` will select row 32 of the data.frame.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm experimenting with different fixes. I still get the same error message when using the approach you recommended, it seems that I cannot pass commands to the subsetted data frame.